# Simple table adapter Update Failing

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm getting an error message:

> requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection

The update command I am providing is very similar to the preceding line of code - how do I fix this?

The data base being used is very simple. Two tables with a one to many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE [db].dbo.tb_TestHOLDERx
    (
    HolderID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(30),
    "Address" VARCHAR(30),
     CONSTRAINT tb_pkx PRIMARY KEY (HolderID)
    );
    GO
CREATE TABLE [db].dbo.tb_TestALLOTMENTx
    (
    Number  INT NOT NULL,
    HolderID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    "Length" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Paid VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    FloodRisk VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT tb_pkax PRIMARY KEY (Number,HolderID),
     CONSTRAINT tbx_fkx FOREIGN KEY (HolderID)
     REFERENCES dbo.tb_TestHOLDERx(HolderID)
    );
    GO

INSERT INTO [db].dbo.tb_TestHOLDERx
    values
    ('B14','ROY', '3 Stern Way'),
    ('N7','Jamela', '15 Jeune Street');
    GO 
INSERT INTO [db].dbo.tb_TestALLOTMENTx
    values
    (1,'B14',30,'No','Low'),
    (2,'N7',30,'Yes','Medium'),
    (3,'N7',15,'Yes','High');
    GO
```

The Windows form looks like the following:

[image]

The handler for the button "Use Combo ID" click event is:

```
private void useComboID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if(combHOLDER.SelectedIndex!=-1) {
                allotHOLDERid.Text = combHOLDER.Text;
     }
}
```

This then over-writes the value in the left text box with the value selected in the top right combo box.

Then using the Save to DB button I try to save changes to the local dataset and then update the database with the following event handler:

```
private void saveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    tbTestHOLDERxBindingSource.EndEdit();
    tbTestALLOTMENTxBindingSource.EndEdit();
    try {
        tb_TestHOLDERxTableAdapter.Update(wHAnalysisDataSet.tb_TestHOLDERx);
        tb_TestALLOTMENTxTableAdapter.Update(wHAnalysisDataSet.tb_TestALLOTMENTx); //<<<<<<ERROR HERE
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
    } catch(Exception x) {
        MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
    }
}
```

If I comment out the marked line of code then it runs through ok but with this line I get the previously detaioled error.

How do I amend the Update so it writes the change back to the DB?

Comment: How do you build other commands for your adapter? Automatically using SqlCommandBuilder or coding manually? I guess your adapter misses an UpdateCommand.

Comment: @KingKing The data set has only two tables in it. Both of the Adapters were automatically generated when I bound the controls to these tables.

Comment: @KingKing ok - found the answer and I'll post it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In this MSDN posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/666835a2-50ec-415f-ba30-bb80ca51c91b)

> Try this, it worked to me:
>
> Go to edit dataset with designer (you can go there from the "Data"
>   menu then "show data sources" and "Edit dataset with designer".
>
> Right click the adapter and select "Configure". Click "Advanced
>   options". Make sure the "Refresh the data table" is selected. Click OK
>   and Finish.
>
> Tell me if it works. Good luck.

Comment: Nice to know you've solved it. I'm not familiar with using Wizard. I like coding manually. :)

Comment: @KingKing  I suspect that using code or using the wizard the solution would have involved the same properties. I love code. The wizards associated with table adapters and binding sources are really growing on me - they seem very powerful and save lots of time. They make tracking down bugs quite tricky though :)

Comment: I agree, I will surely learn how to use wizard, in fact there are only some wizards I haven't learnt. and all the wizards seem to involve database project. While I'm not really interested in database project. I like Graphics, System and Advanced algorithm-related projects :)